# Excel VBA - matching value from array to array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm comparing 2 array. 1 is dynamic array and 1 is static array, both are 1-Dimension array with different size. The condition is that if the value in the dynamic array matches to the value in the static array, then it would take cell values and some other action would happens.

example case:

```
dynArr = (123,123,45,23,56,90,34,Nil) ' size based on row counts
staArr = (90,60,30,0)
```

So if any value in `dynArr` matches to `staArr`, some thing happens.

Right now, I think that something is wrong with my condition as it gets all the values from the excel rows.

I tried used `application.match()` but with description from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel), it does not seem to work and in terms of speed wise, it much more slower from [some](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/07/03/find-matching-data-in-array-speed-test/) [other posts](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/).

How should I change my condition to match between arrays? or is there any workaround?

```
Sub getValue()

'define dynamic array
Dim sn, sb, interval, daysleft As Variant
'define static array
interval = Array(90, 60, 30, 14, 7, 0, -2)

Dim cnt As Long
Dim i, x, y As Long

ReDim sn(1 To 1)
ReDim sb(1 To 1)
ReDim daysleft(1 To 1)

cnt = 0

'Loop through all the row
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    'redim daysleft based on the rows
    ReDim Preserve daysleft(1 To i)
    daysleft(i) = Cells(i, "L").Value

    For x = LBound(daysleft) To UBound(daysleft)
     For y = LBound(interval) To UBound(interval)

        If daysleft(x) = interval(y) Then 'Loops everything

            'assign cell value to array
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve sn(1 To cnt)
            ReDim Preserve sb(1 To cnt)

            sn(cnt) = Cells(i, "A").Value
            sb(cnt) = Cells(i, "F").Value

         End If
        Next y
    Next x
Next i

For i = 1 To (cnt - 1)
    Debug.Print "This is sn: "; sn(i) 'gets all the value instead of the matching case
  'Call test(sn(i), sb(i))
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can try to avoid doing all those ReDim Preserves especially inside loops. If possible oversize initially and then resize at end (using a counter variable which has tracked the number of elements added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think this is what you want.  I commented out the For x loop. The i loop that you had loads up all of the daysleft. Having the x loop was causing you the match the same value in the interval more than once.

```
Sub getValue()

    'define dynamic array
    Dim sn, sb, interval, daysleft As Variant
    'define static array
    interval = Array(90, 60, 30, 14, 7, 0, -2)

    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i, x, y As Long

    ReDim sn(1 To 1)
    ReDim sb(1 To 1)
    ReDim daysleft(1 To 1)

    cnt = 0

    ' Loop through all the row
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).row
        'redim daysleft based on the rows
        ReDim Preserve daysleft(1 To i)
        daysleft(i) = Cells(i, "L").Value

        'For x = LBound(daysleft) To UBound(daysleft)
            For y = LBound(interval) To UBound(interval)

               If daysleft(i) = interval(y) Then 'Loops everything

               'assign cell value to array
               cnt = cnt + 1
               ReDim Preserve sn(1 To cnt)
               ReDim Preserve sb(1 To cnt)

               sn(cnt) = Cells(i, "A").Value
               sb(cnt) = Cells(i, "F").Value

            End If
            Next y
         'Next x
     Next i

     For i = 1 To (cnt)
          Debug.Print "This is sn: "; sn(i) 'gets all the value instead of the matching case
         'Call test(sn(i), sb(i))
     Next

End Sub
```