# VBA Comparing Arrays of Different Length Run-time Error 9

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an Excel file that houses the name of tables and their corresponding columns as follows: [image] I have written a sub procedure that returns all corresponding Table names for the name of a column.

My current code does the following:

1. Saves Col A (table names) and Col B (column names) to a 2D array
2. Looks through the array to find if the name of the table exists in column one of the array.
3. If the Column name exists, then a counter is increased and another array is re-dimensioned each time the value occurs in the array.
4. I then set that array equal to the original array and return that array of Table names back to the sheet.

I have an error handler in there that says if the values saved in to an array called `str_array` is <> the `Big_Array(i,1)` (the col A table names) but the name of the User Input `Col_LookupValue` IS in `Big_Array(i,1)` then show the following message:

```
"You must enter the name of the Column, NOT the Table."
```

My issue is that I am getting the "Runtime Error 9" Subscript out of range error when comparing the str_array(r,1) to the Big_array(i,1) in the nested for loops.

Does anybody know why that is and how to fix it.

Note: I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088014/excel-vba-matching-value-from-array-to-array?rq=1)

Thank you for any ideas, suggestions, or answers in advance!!!

Here is the full code:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Col_LookupValue As String
Sub LookUpColName()

    Dim str_array(), Big_Array(), small_array() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Col_LookupValue_Counter As Long
    Dim col_lkupval_found As Boolean


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    'clear previously returned data
     Worksheets("New TRAX").Range("C2:D300").ClearContents

        'Store cols A and B in the Big_Array
        Big_Array = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

                str_array = Array("AUDIT_REQUEST", "EMPLOYEE_CONTROL", "GLOBAL_NAME", "OID$", "PN_INTERCHANGEABLE", "PN_RESTRICTION", "TASK_CARD", "TASK_CARD_ITEM", "TASK_CARD_RESOLUTION_ITEM", "UOM_CONVERSION", "WO")


        'Starting in the second row of the Big_Array loop through each Big_Array
        For i = LBound(Big_Array, 1) To UBound(Big_Array, 1)

            'Note: I used Option Compare Text at the _
            beginning of the module to make the text _
            comparisons non case sensitive
             For r = LBound(str_array, 1) To UBound(str_array, 1)
             If Big_Array(i, 1) <> str_array(r, 1) And Col_LookupValue = Big_Array(i, 1) Then

              MsgBox "You must enter the name of the Column, NOT the Table", vbExclamation, "Error Encountered"

                Exit Sub


            ElseIf Big_Array(i, 2) Like Col_LookupValue Then

                'excecutes below if this is true
                col_lkupval_found = True

                'increase the Col_LookupValue_Counter by 1 each _
                time the Col_LookupValue matches a value in col B
                Col_LookupValue_Counter = Col_LookupValue_Counter + 1

                'Redimension the small_array array with each instance _
                of a the Col_LookupValue in the Big_Array.
                ReDim Preserve _
                small_array(1 To 2, 1 To Col_LookupValue_Counter)
                   'Start a j counter to populate the small_array array; _
                    note, that 2 To 2 subsets the array and only pulls the _
                    SECOND column of it
                    For j = 1 To 1
                    'The small_array array equals the current Big_Array
                          small_array(j, Col_LookupValue_Counter) _
                          = Big_Array(i, j)
                    Next j
            End If
          Next r
        Next i

            'If no 'Like' was found then show the message box
            If col_lkupval_found = False Then
               MsgBox "You must enter the the full name of the Column.", vbExclamation, "Column Name Does Not Exist"
               Exit Sub
            End If


        'Transpose the small_array onto sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2", Range("C2").Offset(Col_LookupValue_Counter - 1, 1)) _
        = Application.Transpose(small_array)

      'Write Col_LookupValue to sheet
      Worksheets("New TRAX").Cells(2, 4).Value2 = Col_LookupValue

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I have also tried without the str_array() and when I use only 1 condition Like so:

```
If Big_Array(i, 1) <> "Table_Name" And Col_LookupValue = Big_Array(i, 1) Then
```

The code works exactly as intended. 
However, when I try this:

```
If (Big_Array(i, 1) <> "Table_Name1" Or Big_Array(i, 1) <> "Table_Name2" Or Big_Array(i, 1) <> "Table_Name3") And Col_LookupValue = Big_Array(i, 1) Then
```

The error is thrown even when the Col_LookUpValue=Table_Name1, 2 so on.

Comment: Unlike `Big_Array`,  `str_array` is a 1-D array, so you can't reference an element using (eg) `str_array(0,1)`   You just use (eg) `str_array(0)`.   Likewise you would typically not write `LBound(str_array, 1)` (although that will not error) but `LBound(str_array)`

Comment: In your last line of code those `Or` should probably be `And`

Comment: Tim Williams is right with the array dimensions. You can get help of such errors but putting a breakpoint to the specific line and use **"View->Locals Windows"**. You can see that your `str_array` has only one index while `Big_array` has two.

Comment: Lack of sleep has not served me well this morning, lol! Mr. Williams you are a gentleman and scholar!!! The simple change of `Or` to `And` did the trick! Thank you to all for your help!